# Insert an element in between divs that have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page having this structure :: consecutive divs have the same class but each of its child div has a unique id.

```
<div class = 'samediv'>
    <div id = 'onediv'></div>
</div>
<div class = 'samediv'>
    <div id = 'twodiv'></div>
</div>
<div class = 'samediv'>
    <div id = 'thirddiv'></div>
</div>
```

Now on clicking the unique div, how can I insert another div/element after its parent.

For example, on clicking **onediv**, I want a div (say, **unique**) in between **onediv**'s parent and **twodiv**'s parent.

The structure then becomes:

```
<div class = 'samediv'>
    <div id = 'onediv'></div>
</div>
<div id = "unique">
</div>
<div class = 'samediv'>
    <div id = 'twodiv'></div>
</div>
<div class = 'samediv'>
    <div id = 'thirddiv'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a class selector to these divs with IDs? for example, `<div id = 'onediv' class='childdiv'></div>` and `<div id = 'twodiv' class='childdv'></div>` and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".samediv > div").on("click", function() {
    $("<div />", { id: "unique" }).insertAfter(this.parentNode);
});
```

Note, that instead `"unique"` there should be something *really* unique.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4MRwZ/

Comment: @VisionN .. can u please explain what the statement inside the function does?

Comment: @Mellkor `$("<div />", { id: "unique" })` creates new `<div>` element with `id` as `"unique"` and inserts it after parent node of the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.samediv > div").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().after("<div id='unique'></div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$('.samediv').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().after('<div id = "unique"> </div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

example :

```
$("#onediv").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div id = "unique"></div>')
})
```

required

```
$(".samediv > div").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div id = "unique"></div>')
})
```